# .ajax() post request to send JSON data to server only works in debug mode

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

I'm trying to add a json string to the DB, and calling a web-service in the URL of the ajax call. The string is inserted in the DB when I step through the code with the chrome debugger. However, if I don't run in debug mode, I get an error message whose response text is blank.

I know the problem is **NOT** with the web serbvice as it works fine independantly. Does anyone know why this may happen?

#### Here's some code

```
var object1 = { obj: 'newobj2' };
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',              
            url: 'saveJSON.asmx/submitToDB',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: object1,
            success: function () { alert("success"); },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("error: " + response.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably due to caching. Try setting cache to `false` in the request.

```
   $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',              
        url: 'saveJSON.asmx/submitToDB',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: object1,
        success: function () { alert("success"); },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("error: " + response.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried this, it worked for the first time after I ran and added the string to the DB, however, after that it continued to cache, and even when I changed the string, the same previous cached string got added every other time I ran it.

Comment: Everytime this string changes, I need to first "Build" from Visual Studio.

Comment: For anyone who has a similar problem, I solved this by using an UpdatePanel